# Using the current value of an object's attribute

Tags: javascript, function, class, variables, attributes

I'm really new to programming and JavaScript as well, and I can't seem to get this one to work.

What I want to do is to use the current value of an object's `x` and give the same value to another object created from another class inside the first class.

```
function MyClass() {
        this.x = 0;

        this.move = function () {
                this.x += 10;           // I can adjust the x when I call the move
                console.log(this.x)     // Prints out the current position
        }

        function doSmthng () {
                var obj = new OtherClass();
                obj.x = this.x;         // Doesn't work, I can't use the current position 
                console.log(this.x)     // Prints out undefined
        }
}

function OtherClass() {
    this.x = 0;
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure if I expressed myself correctly, or if I'm using the correct terms or anything, but any help would be more than pleasant!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you calling the doSmthng method? It is not exposed. If from inside the constructor then you need to use the apply method, if from outside it should work but I guess you are not doing it because you didn't attach the method to the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function doSmthng is not a member of your MyClass class. You have to write `this.doSmthng = function ()`. Note: x won't update automatically in OtherClass when you change x in MyClass again, because it's a number (value type). You have to pass an object to make that automatic synchronisation work.